# Getters y Setters en Java

Tags: java, java-8

¿Existe algún método de anotación en `Java 8` (o anteriores) para tener en una clase POJO al menos los métodos Getters y Setters sin necesidad de escribirlos? Hablo de algo parecido a lo que en `C#` se hace así:

```
public string Code { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Details { get; set; }
```

He visto que hay librerías de terceros para hacerlo, como el [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), pero busco si se puede hacer directamente con el JDK de Java

**UPDATE**: no busco cómo escribir getters y setters, sino todo lo contrario, cómo no escribirlos, al estilo de C#

Comment: click derecho --> insertar codigo ----> una lista con las opciones(Constructores con/sin argumentos, getter and setters, toString(), equals...)

Comment: No es lo que pregunto :(. Pregunto la forma de ahorrarme tener escritos los getters y setters mediante anotaciones

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque Java8 es demasiado antiguo ya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo que necesitas desde Java , pero no de forma nativa debes descargar la libreria [lombok](/questions/tagged/lombok) añadirla a tu proyecto y luego debes añadir las anotaciones (@Getter @Setter) a tus variables .

link proyecto lombok : https://projectlombok.org/

Comment: Mientras que lombok da la magia de evitar la creación de getters y setters, en realidad él agrega este código previo al tiempo de compilación. No escribirás el código pero sí está presente.

Comment: Acabo de ver en la Java Magazine de este mes que hasta Oracle recomienda este proyecto http://www.javamagazine.mozaicreader.com/MayJune2017

Answer (score 3):

Personalmente he usado la librería [lombok](/questions/tagged/lombok), ha sido muy útil para mi, permite generar los `getters` y `setters` a través del uso de anotaciones. Por ejemplo:

```
@Getter @Setter private int code;
```

Este es el link:

> https://projectlombok.org/

En su sitio web hay un video que explica su uso, la documentación es bastante clara y tiene soporte para varios IDEs. Espero que te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no existe estimado.

Solo existe el hecho de definir variables, y luego colocar la construcción a través de click derecho, insertar código y aparece construcción de Getters y Setters.

Ahora bien, no entiendo cual es tu objetivo, puesto a que en C# se ve mas corto el código y en java mas extenso, pero ambos son rápidos de crear considerando que se han hecho tecnologías que apuntan a la creación rápida de estos objetos.

La siguiente imagen a pesar que como hablabas, no se tiene un codigo mas pequeño, te ayuda visualmente a que todo este acoplado, lo que hace mas sencillo a la vista. Pero como te vuelvo a indicar, no existe lo que tu formulas en JDK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!

Comment: El objetivo es no tener clases grandes con getters y setters

Comment: modifique la respuesta, para darte otra perspectiva, que a pesar que no es lo que buscas, es una "solución" visual. Saludos y Exito

Answer (score 0):

Escribir una propiedad de la forma `string Code { get; set; }` cuando ni el método `get` ni el `set` aportan ninguna variación al comportamiento (simplemente devuelven el valor de la variable), no dista mucho a establecer la variable como `public` y obtener o modificar su valor directamente.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta: La forma más sencilla de simular la notación de `propiedad`de `C#` en `JAVA`, cuando los métodos `get` y `set` actúan por defecto, es declarar el campo como `public`.

El encapsulamiento se rompe tanto si todos los campos son `public`como si todos los campos tienen un `get`y `set` por defecto.

Comment: Es una de las característica de C# que más me gustaría que tuviera Java, junto con el uso de hacer las llamadas a getters y setters directamente en expresiones (así, `x = y + x` en realidad se compila como `setX(getY() + getX())`; cuál es más fácil de leer?) Y no tiene nada que ver con hacer una variable `public`; es muy útil porque, a diferencia de una variable global, cuando necesitas añadir cualquier lógica (una comprobación de valor en el `set`, o simplemente un `log`) no necesitas modificar las expresiones que usan esa propiedad.

Answer (score -3):

aunque no sea la solución a tu problema, si haces un rightclick sobre el código, Source >> Getters and Setters, te los puede generar

Siento no conocer la solución exacta, pero quizás esto ayuda

Comment: Esto no aporta nada a la pregunta.

Comment: No aporta a la respuesta, considerando que fue exactamente lo mismo que se escribió en un comentario, y se menciono que no era el objetivo.